# JavaScript set a form fields initial value, to the same value of another field?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I am trying to handle some JavaScript work, which I don't have much experience with. I have a 2 part form where a user enters their personal info, and then company info. I am trying to set some of the company fields to what they already entered in their personal info.

I don't want the user to have to retype address, email, etc.

for example, I have...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email<span>*</span></label>
    <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control required" id="email"placeholder="Email" value=". 
        {{email}}">
    <span id="span_email" class="error-msg"></span>
```

And...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comp_email">Company Email<span>*</span></label>
    <input name="comp_email" type="text" class="form-control required" id="comp_email"placeholder="Email" 
        value="{{comp_email}}">
    <span id="span_email" class="error-msg"></span>
```

How would I be able to set that second `comp_email` field to initially have the `email` info, so the user doesn't have to retype, unless they actually wanted to change the `comp_email` to another email address?

## EDIT

It is all in one form, just separated by divs. Initially, when the page is loaded, the account section div is displayed, when the user hits next, it triggers the display of the business info.

```
 <input type="button" onclick="nextFormPage(); window.scrollTo(0, 100)" 
    class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Next">
```

The `nextFormPage()` function just hides the first div and displays the second div.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. Using the Django framework.

Comment: What you are looking for isn't clear. Are these inputs on the same page or separate pages? If they are the same page, what trigger should cause the data to be filled into the second form-group? If they are separate pages, please show us more information about how the form submits to the second page.

Comment: just use onchange event handler on email and update company email if changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged both javascript and jQuery so I'm not sure which you are using. But you can do this with a single line either way:

**Javascript:**:

```
document.getElementById("comp_email").value = document.getElementById("email").value;
```

`document.getElementById("email").value` gets the value from the email input and we set the value of the `document.getElementById("comp_email")` by setting its `value` attribute:

**jQuery:**

```
$("#comp_email").val( $("#email").val() );
```

`$("#email").val()` get the value from the email input and `$("#comp_email").val( ... );` sets the text passed in as the input value.

**Javascript Working Example**

```js
function nextFormPage(){
    document.getElementById("comp_email").value = document.getElementById("email").value;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email<span>*</span></label>
    <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control required" id="email" placeholder="Email" value="">
    <span id="span_email" class="error-msg"></span>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="comp_email">Company Email<span>*</span></label>
    <input name="comp_email" type="text" class="form-control required" id="comp_email" placeholder="Email" 
        value="">
    <span id="span_email" class="error-msg"></span>


 <input type="button" onclick="nextFormPage(); window.scrollTo(0, 100)" 
    class="btn btn-danger btn-block" value="Next">
```

Answer (score 0):

If your user is logged in, you should pass all of their information to the form, including their email. For example:

```
const logIn = () => {
... some code to get the user ...
... pass the user to the form, probably through an event listener...
let button = document.createElement("button")
button.textContent = "Edit"
button.addEventListener('click', () => {editYourStuff(user)}
}

const editYourStuff = user => {
... grab whatever your form is called ...
 editForm.email.value = user.email
}
```

This should pre populate your form with the email